# Maintain a list of bounding client rectangles in a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which must be aware of the position of all nodes contained within it.

```
class ContextAwareGrid extends Component {
  state = { nodes: { } };
  render() {
    return (<div className="grid">
      {this.renderNodes()}
    </div>);
  }
  renderNodes() {
    return Object.entries().map(entry => {
      const [ id, node ] = entry;
      return (<GridNode
        key={id}
        id={id}
        {...node}
      />);
    });
  }
}
```

My goal is to find the distance of a node along an axis relative to another node as they are moving. The problem is, in order to do this, I will need to know the `getBoundingClientRect` property in the parent for when any child moves.

The most naive answer I've found is to include a `ref` while instancing the components that calls a function like:

```
onComponentMounted = (id, component) => {
  this.setState(state => {
    const rect = component.getBoundingClientRect();
    state.elements[id] = rect;
    return state;
  });
}
```

However, this causes problems whenever the component is moved or otherwise changed.

My last attempts yielded `Maximum Call Stack Exceeded`, so obviously, I came to stack overflow to fix the problem

Is there any way to maintain references to all child components of a specific class in the parent component?

Comment: I didn't realise you could pass a callback as the first argument to `setState`...

Comment: yeah it's listed [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm not sure that you should be mutating the state object like that anyway. Presumably you can just return the slice of the state that you want to update, i.e. `{ elements: ... }`, and make a new copy of the value rather than modifying `state.elements` in place.